# What's the differences between `Combine` and `didSet` in Swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I recently worked on SwiftUI and starting writing code in a declarative way. But here comes a confusion. Like what is shown below, I want to (1)load the song data and (2)show the view by setting `isInfoViewShown`, after `song` is assigned to any value.

I assume `didSet{}` and `Combine @Published .sink{}` are doing things interchangeably. So I want to ask what are the differences between them? And in my own opinion, `didSet{}` can do most of jobs `Combine` do. So why should Apple announce `Combine` framework?

Any help is appreciated.

```
class InfoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var song: Song? {
        didSet {                      // Here's the didSet{}: [1] load song data
            if let song = song {
                load(song: song)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var songSelectedSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    @Published var isInfoViewShown: Bool = false

    init() {                          // Here's the Combine @Published .sink{}: [2] show the view
        songSelectedSubscription = $song.sink{ self.isInfoViewShown = ($0 == nil ? false : true) }              
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, if `@Published` were the only kind of publisher in the universe, Combine would arguably be superfluous. But it isn't! Combine exists. Given that, we need a Combine way to do what `didSet` does. `@Published`, in part, is it.

Comment: Bet. Apply a filter and debounce using `didSet`. Good luck! :D

Comment: May I conclude that `didSet` and `willSet` just have a basic functionality, while `Combine` is another more advanced tool to handle not only what `didSet` can do, but also some more advanced works easily, e.g. map, filter and debounce. These works also can be done by `didSet`, but a lot of codes are required. So, `Combine` wins the race completely when it comes to advanced fields.

Comment: @Air Just about. Often you might use the two together. When bridging with non-combine code, you might use a `didSet` observer to detect changes, and then publish those to a Combine pipeline (typically using a `PassthroughSubject` or `CurrentValueSubject`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there are lots of ways to observe changes to data, KVO, Notification Center, didSet, combine etc, so in one sense these things are indeed similar.  Differences though are:

a property can only have one didSet, which makes it hard for any number of observers to register an interest in the property.

But the big win with Combine is: a Combine pipeline allows you to create streams easily where you can say for example, transform the stream of changes to a stream that: observes changes to the user's input string, debounces it (rate limiting changes so we don't spam the server), filter those changes for any value that is at least 3 characters long, and that produces a new stream which you can observe.  Map/FlatMap is also a really important combine operator, transform a stream of a's into a stream of b's.  Also merging two streams together with combineLatest and so on, so you can take a stream of a's and stream of b's and make a stream of (a, b)'s and then map that to a stream of validated c's, for example.

Comment: Also very important to note that `@Published` uses `willSet` semantics, not `didSet`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor What does it mean? I suppose that `@Published` is used to publish the change "after" the data is actually changed, but `willSet` does it "before" the data changed.

Comment: @Air quite the opposite. `@Published` emits the value from `willSet`, so it publishes the new value _before_ the property would actually be set. `didSet` is called _after_ `willSet`, when the property was already updated. You used `didSet` in your question to compare with `@Published`, hence I wanted to clarify.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableObject` is designed to hold the model structs. For view data like `isInfoViewShown` that should be `@State` in the `View` struct. In SwiftUI the `View` struct is comparable to the view model object in UIKit it looks like you are used to. Since it is a struct (value) type is faster and less error-prone. You can extract related `@State var` into their own struct using `mutating func` for testable logic which you probably did in your view model objects. A `View` struct will automatically call body when a `let` or a `@State var` value changes, this dependency tracking is built-in to SwiftUI, you no-longer need to use Combine for this like you might in UIKit.

FYI when we use Combine inside the `ObservableObject` we `assign` the end of the pipeline to the `@Published` we don't tend to use `sink` because then we would need to perform manual cancellation in `deinit` whereas `assign` does that automatically. Inside the `@Published` auto-genenerated `willSet`, it calls `objectWillChange.send()` which SwiftUI coalesces multiple of into a single recalculation of `body` in any `View` struct that use `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` (regardless of the object's properties accessed or not - `let` and `@State var` are more optimal in that regard).